# restore files from Ubuntu one impossible

Tags: ubuntu-one, gnupg

My laptop was stolen, it had Ubuntu One installed on it. Now I have a new laptop, again with Ubuntu One. When I access my account I can see lots of files from the old one but I can't restore them in a readable form.

I tried the steps I found on the web but the files are still encrypted, I have no idea what to do with all those `gpg` files in the folder. I just want to restore them on the new laptop and see what I can recover from all the info I've lost. One of the replies I found on the net said that they will automatically appear in the new Ubuntu One folder. However, they do not.

Answer (score 1):

If you encrypted your individual files before they were uploaded to Ubuntu One, and are thus stored encrypted on the server, then Ubuntu One only knows about the encrypted data you uploaded. It will only download these files as they exist on the server. You will need the private key you used for encrypting them, in order to decrypt them. If that was on your stolen laptop, and you don't have a copy or back-up of that private key to use, you will be unable to decrypt the files. That has nothing to do with Ubuntu One.

If you have files visible on https://one.ubuntu.com/files/ which are not being downloaded to your machine, and you have subscribed to the folders those files exist in, on your machine, then you should contact Ubuntu One support at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ for further assistance.

Comment: +1, this is exactly the desired result for encrypted files. No key = junk data.